# How to configure "accept Terms and Conditions" on Keycloak registration page

Tags: keycloak

I use Keycloak 1.7.0-Final. The user must agree with Term and Conditions at registration.

I enabled "Terms and Conditions" in Authentication > Required actions, But nothing is shown on the registration page.

Also, I cannot find where to configure specific Terms and Condition files for each language.

Could you help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

By default existing users cannot have this page. You need to configure "Terms and Conditions" as "Default Action", then this will be applied by default for all new users.

For existing users, you need to put it manually unser "Users" > "Required actions".

Dont forget to customize the terms page under //themes/base/login/terms.ftl

Comment: Do you know if it is possible create different "terms and conditions" per client?

Comment: @user60108 each client can have their own login theme configured.  To do that you could make extension(s) with different login themes with different terms and conditions pages and configure each client to use a different login theme.

Answer (score 7):

You will see terms and conditions once the user has filled in the registration form and submits registration. You will have to override the terms.ftl (build your own theme) page if you want it customized and add your own messages locale - see [Keycloak Docs - Themes](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/themes.html) ...

Comment: Dead link, try this one for themes: https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-developer-guide/content/topics/themes.html, this one for terms and conditions: https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/users/required-actions.html

Comment: Double Dead. Try this link:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/server_admin/topics/users/required-actions.html

Comment: Again dead. See https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#required-actions

Answer (score 1):

## Enable terms and conditions

Regularly you must enable "Terms and Conditions" in Authentication > Required Actions as **Enabled** and **Default Action**. By default, this will show a dedicated page after the registration form page, using the template terms.ftl.

## Using a checkbox for accepting terms and conditions in the registration page

For this purpose you must specify terms and conditions as **Enabled**, but not a **Default Action**. Otherwise you will see the dedicated page using terms.ftl. The problem here is that Keycloak has not a way to enable a checkbox to accept the terms and conditions in the registration page.
Nonetheless, doing a little of reverse engineering I found that when you accept the conditions the user will have an attribute called `terms_and_conditions`:

[image: User attributes after the user was created]

In order to reproduce this, you just need to create a custom attribute, named **terms_and_conditions**, with a numeric value, that seems to be the current time (`Date.now()`). Being that said, you need an HTML like:

```
<form>
  <!-- other inputs -->
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="terms"
      name="user.attributes.terms_and_conditions"
      value="<generated value, e.g. 1668029792010>" />
    <label for="terms">I accept the terms and conditions</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Create user</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This approach should also be valid if you create that user using the API.

## i18n

If your are using a checkbox in the registration page, you can use the standard internationalisation strategy: using the messages properties files. It would probably have a link that reference the content of the "terms and conditions" in the current language. To get the lang code to construct the URL use `${locale.currentLanguageTag}`.

### Show a page for each language

On the other hand, if you want to use the typical Keycloak strategy using `terms.ftl`, then you must use the same layout as always and the text will change using the internationalisation.
But if the content of the terms and conditions is very long, then it should be better to create pages for each language, e.g. `terms-en.ftl`, `terms-fr.ftl`, etc. These ftl files will only contain the content in the corresponding language and they will be loaded using a code like:

```
<#include "terms-fr.ftl" />
```

e.g.

```
  <#if (locale.currentLanguageTag!"en") == "en">
     <#include "terms-en.ftl" />
  <#else>
     <#include "terms-es.ftl" />
  </#if>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Wow, thanks, interesting idea. I am gonna try that.
One question: Do you know if that timestamp value of terms_and_conditions attribute affects anything? You mentioned the Date.now() should be used in the template but you have the timestamp hardcoded instead in your snippet. Is it OK to just hardcode it?

Comment: @NikitaMendelbaum I have tested and so far so good, so I dont think it affects anything. No, you should not hardcode it, I just did not wanted to focus very much in the Javascript function, because you can get this value in multiple ways, even using freemarker.

Answer (score 1):

For Keycloak v22+, I have found two methods of requiring terms and conditions (T&C) to be accepted. Both don't require editing .ftl files or building your own Docker image. Only editing the configuration which makes it easier to use than the approaches suggested by [@joseph-garrone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72035267/6783666), [@eliux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74381814/6783666) and [@saberkan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55690027/6783666).

One approach is directly on the registration page and the other as a second step after registration (as used on [inamata.co](https://inamata.co)). If you use identity providers (e.g., sign in via your Google or Microsoft account) I would recommend using the second option of using a second page as otherwise only users registering directly will have to accept your T&C.

### T&C On Registration Page

1. Create a new realm (or use an existing one)
2. Go to Authentication page --> Required Actions tab
3. Enable Terms and Conditions action (not set as default action)
4. In the Flows tab, duplicate the registration flow (use the three dots on the right to open the menu)
5. Edit the duplicated flow (Copy of Registration should be the default name)
6. Press the plus button on the right end of the Copy of registration registration flow row and select add step. This opens a different selection than the Add Step button above the steps table.
7. Select Terms and Conditions
8. Set Terms and Conditions as a required step
9. To change the text displayed on the registration page go to Realm Settings and the Localization tab
10. Press add message bundle and use `termsText` as the key and any HTML as the value

The backend supports validation and will return an error message if the T&C are not accepted. The Keycloak docs provide [additional info](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#proc-requiring-tac-agreement-at-registration_server_administration_guide).

### T&C After Registration

1. Create a new realm (or use an existing one)
2. Go to Authentication page --> Required Actions tab
3. Enable Terms and Conditions action and set as default action
4. To change the text displayed on the registration page go to Realm Settings and the Localization tab
5. Press add message bundle and use `termsText` as the key and any HTML as the value

After registering or logging in, the user is presented with a page to accept or decline the T&C. If they accept, an attribute (`terms_and_conditions`) is added to the user with the timestamp when they accepted them. If they decline, issuing a token will fail. When using keycloak-angular/keycloak-js npm packages, they will throw an error which can be caught and the trigger a dialog to inform the user that they have to refresh the page and accept the T&C to use the app.

### Localization

Both of the above approaches support localization. All that has to be done is enable internationalization in the localization tab on the realm settings page. Then, for each supported language, add a message bundle with the same key and the translated value.

### Exposing T&C in Token

It is also possible to expose the time and whether the user accepted the T&C in the token returned by Keycloak on login.

1. Go to the clients page and select your client
2. On the Client Scopes tab select the `<client-name>-dedicated` scope. Should be the first one
3. Press `Add mapper`, then `By conifiguration` and select `User Attribute`
4. Enter a name, use `terms_and_conditions` as the User attribute, enter any value token claim name (will be the JSON key name in the token)
5. Finally set Claim JSON Type to integer, select the token types you want it applied to and press save.
6. Log in with a user that has accepted the T&C, decode the token (with [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)) and you should find the timestamp listed there.

### Common Notes

You can see the implementation of the second step after registration in action on [app.inamata.co](https://app.inamata.co).

In the message bundle text it is possible to use <ul>, <li> and <a> tags to format the T&C links. The source for the keys can be extracted from `/opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-themes-x.y.z.jar`. In this case its the `<jar/zip file>/theme/base/login/messages/messages_X.properties` file. The official docs are useful for further info ([theming](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes)).

It might make sense to use the `--spi-theme-static-max-age=-1 --spi-theme-cache-themes=false --spi-theme-cache-templates=false` options when launching Keycloak to disable theme caching.

```
docker run \
      -p "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" \
      -e "KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin" \
      -e "KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin" \
      -d \
      quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.5-0 \
      start-dev --spi-theme-static-max-age=-1 --spi-theme-cache-themes=false --spi-theme-cache-templates=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Keycloakify](http://keycloakify.dev) to create a theme.
[Here](https://docs.keycloakify.dev/terms-and-conditions) is the section related to customizing Terms and conditions.